# What is Qt? And where do I get it?

Tags: installation, qt

How do I install Qt-devel (4.5)? Where do I get it?

I need to compile cpp files into an executable. I have no idea how this works.

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you want to do. What are you trying to compile?

Answer (score 3):

[Qt is a cross-platform application and UI framework.](http://qt.nokia.com/) It includes a cross-platform class library, integrated development tools and a cross-platform IDE. Using Qt, you can write web-enabled applications once and deploy them across many desktop and embedded operating systems without rewriting the source code.

Source and sdk can be downloaded [here](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads)

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28framework%29):

> Qt is a cross-platform application
>   development framework widely used for
>   the development of GUI programs (in
>   which case it is known as a widget
>   toolkit), and also used for developing
>   non-GUI programs such as console tools
>   and servers.
>
> Qt is most notably used in Google
>   Earth, KDE, Opera (before 10.60
>   version), OPIE, Skype, MO-Call, VLC
>   media player and VirtualBox. It is
>   produced by Nokia's Qt Development
>   Frameworks division, which came into
>   being after Nokia's acquisition of the
>   Norwegian company Trolltech, the
>   original producer of Qt, on June 17,
>   2008.

Please see the related Wikipedia [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28framework%29) and these [external links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28framework%29#External_links) to find out more.

Answer (score 1):

As the answers above say, it's a cross platform C++ framework.

When you say qt-devel, it sounds like a specific package.  Your Linux comes as a series of packages that you can then install with a package manager.  What distribution (e.g. Fedora, Ubuntu) are you using?  This is a common, core package.  You should be able to use the software update tool for your specific Linux to get this package.